# ¿Cómo crear una cookie con características avanzada PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Tengo el siguiente código que toma el dato de la URL, en sí, específicamente el código de referencia `site.com/register/?ref=1234`.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $url_referred = $_GET['ref'];
    setcookie("referred", $url_referred);
    //Reference time 86400 = 1 day && 60*60*24*90 = 90 days && 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 30 days
    setcookie('referred', $url_referred, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    $referred = isset($_COOKIE["referred"]) ? $_COOKIE["referred"] : '';
    //setcookie("referred", "", time()-(86400 * 30));
?>
```

Ahora puedo leer el código de referencia ya sea mediante `echo $_COOKIE["referred"];` yo lo tengo defenido de la siguiente forma para leerlo:

```
if($referred != ""){
    echo $referred;
} else {
    $referred = "0000";//Defaul for my site
}
```

La `cookie` no parece funcionar, al volver abrir doblemente el sitio, pero esta vez si en el dato de la referencia `site.com/register/` el código de referencia ya no se muestra.

Y creo saber porque, primeramente porque el `cookie` establecido se reemplaza por otro fácilmente en el caso anterior por uno vació o dato nulo, porque el que pasa a mostrar es el dato de referencia por defaul, y si realizo lo consiguiente `site.com/register/?ref=123` me muestra el siguiente dato `123` y si vuelvo realizar lo siguiente pero con referencia distinta `site.com/register/?ref=123456` me vuelve a mostrar lo consiguiente `123456` eliminando el anterior.

Entonces, como puedo definir ciertos parámetros y condiciones a una `cookie`, si un usuario llega primeramente a mi sitio sin ningún enlace de referencia el dato a registrar en la `cookie` será el valor por defaul `0000`, y si este va y vuelve con un enlace de referencia que este no sea valido, porque el usuario ya conoció mi sitio por sus propios fines y no por un enlace de referencia.

Y si un usuario llega por el siguiente enlace de referencia `site.com/register/?ref=123` que se registre en la `cookie` el valor `123` y sí se va y vuelve con otro enlace de referencia `site.com/register/?ref=123456`que siga mostrando el valor `123` al menos que el usuario haya vuelto con ese enlace de referencia después de 30 días, ahí si que se registre y se muestre el siguiente valor `123456`.

¿Cómo puedo realizarlo y tener las siguientes condiciones en mi `cookie`?

refresco

Comment: ¿Una cookie avanzada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el flujo sería, básicamente:

- Si el usuario ya tiene una cookie `referred` te saltas el resto de las comprobaciones. `$referred` es el valor de la cookie.
- Si el usuario no tiene esa cookie pero envió el parámetro `ref` en el query string, `$referred` es el valor de `$_GET['ref']`.
- Si no se cumplen ninguna de las anteriores, `$referred` es `0000`
- Al final del proceso fijas la cookie en el header de respuesta con el valor que `$referred` haya tomado en el bucle anterior. Esto implica que si te visita semanalmente, su cookie se va renovando por 30 días cada vez.

El código es más o menos esto:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["referred"])) {
   $referred = $_COOKIE['referred'];
} else if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
   $referred = $_GET['ref'];
} else {
   $referred = '0000';
}

setcookie('referred', $referred, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');

echo $referred;
```

Ojo, si el usuario limpia las cookies de su navegador, es como si nunca hubiese visitado tu sitio.

## Bonus Track editado

(repara errores de sintaxis y despliega mensajes informativos)

Para manejar este caso podrías usar el frontend y si detecta la cookie, alojar el valor en el `localStorage` del browser. **El localStorage obliga a la cookie a persistir porfiadamente**. En ese caso el flujo sería:

- Entro al sitio. No tengo cookie. El backend me devuelve la cookie `0000`.
- Verifico si tengo la llave `referred` en localStorage
- Si no la tengo, le asigno el valor de la cookie que me da el backend
- Si la tengo y si su fecha de expiración ya caducó, piso su valor con lo que me entregó el backend.
- Si la tengo y **no ha caducado**, y **su valor es distinto al que me dice el backend**, entonces sobreescribo la cookie con lo que tengo en localStorage. Las visitas o refrescos siguientes ahora sí detectan la cookie desde el backend.

**Sin embargo**, no vas a poder leer directamente la fecha de expiración de la cookie del navegador. Lo que puedes hacer entonces es darle a la cookie el valor del `$referred` concatenado con la fecha de expiración, preferentemente en la forma de un timestamp. En este caso si el referente es `123` podrías asignar a la cookie el valor `123_<timestamp de expiración>`.

## Ejemplo completo funcional

(cambié el separador `|` por un underscore `_` porque el pipe se reescribe a `%7C` y eso complica todo)

En este caso el script completo sería:

```
<?php
$action1 = 'fijó';
$action2 = 'fijó';
$referred = '';
// comprobamos si la cookie existe y tiene el formato valor_<expiración>
if (isset($_COOKIE['referred']) && strpos($_COOKIE['referred'], '_') !== false) {
    $cookie_array = explode('_', $_COOKIE['referred']);
    $referred = $cookie_array[0];
    $action1 = 'detectó';
    $action2 = 'extendió';
} else if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
    $referred = $_GET['ref'];
    $action1 = 'detectó en el parámetro ref';
}
// si no hay referred o está vacío, fijamos el default
if (!$referred) {
    $action1 = 'fijó por defecto';
    $action2 = 'fijó';
    $referred = '0000';
}

$expiration = time() + (86400 * 30);
setcookie('referred', implode('_', [$referred, $expiration]), $expiration, '/');

echo '<p><b>Acción en el backend:</b> <span id="serverside">';
echo sprintf('se %s la cookie con valor %s y se %s su expiración a %s', $action1, $referred, $action2, $expiration);
echo '</span></p>';
?>
<p><b>Detección en el frontend:</b> <span id="cookie_deferred"></span></p>

<p><b>Detección en localStorage:</b> <span id="cookie_localstorage"></span></p>

<script>
    var mensaje, referred, timestamp = parseInt(Date.now()/1000,10), // js usa microsecundos
    cookieDeferredSelector=document.querySelector('#cookie_deferred'),
    localStorageSelector = document.querySelector('#cookie_localstorage'),
    referred_cookie = document.cookie.match(/referred([^;]+)/),
    stored_cookie = localStorage.getItem('referred');

// Si el browser tiene la cookie, sobreescribo el valor default
if(referred_cookie && referred_cookie.length) {
    referred = referred_cookie[1].replace(/^=/,'');
    mensaje='detectó la cookie "referred"';
} else {
    referred = '0000_'+(86400*30+timestamp); // default
    mensaje='no detectó la cookie "referred". Se fijó por defecto una';
}

var referred_array = referred.split('_');
    cookie_value = referred_array[0],
    correct_value = cookie_value,
    cookie_expiration= referred_array[1];

cookieDeferredSelector.innerText=`El browser ${mensaje} con valor ${cookie_value} y expiración ${cookie_expiration}`;
if(stored_cookie!==null) {
    stored_value = stored_cookie.split('_')[0],
    stored_expiration = stored_cookie.split('_')[1];
}


if (stored_cookie === null) {
    localStorageSelector.innerText=`localStorage no tiene una llave "deferred". Se asignó el valor de la cookie: ${referred}`;
// Si no hay nada en localStorage, le pongo el valor de la cookie
   localStorage.setItem('referred', referred);
} else if (stored_expiration > timestamp && stored_value.length && cookie_value!==stored_value) {
   correct_value = stored_value;
   var new_timestamp=timestamp+30*86400,
       new_expiration = new Date(new_timestamp*1000).toGMTString(),
       new_cookie = [stored_value, new_timestamp].join('_');

    localStorageSelector.innerText=`El valor en localStorage ${stored_value} es distinto al de la cookie ${cookie_value}. Se sobreescribió la cookie con ese valor`;
   // Si el localStorage no ha expirado y el backend me devolvió '0000'
   document.cookie=`referred=${new_cookie};expires=${new_expiration}`;
} else if (stored_expiration <= timestamp || !stored_value.length) {
    localStorageSelector.innerText=`El valor en localStorage expiró o no tiene valor. Se le asignó el valor de la cookie: ${referred}`;
    localStorage.setItem('referred', referred);

} else if (cookie_value===stored_value) {
    localStorageSelector.innerText=`El valor almacenado en localStorage coincide con el valor de la cookie: ${cookie_value}`;
    localStorage.setItem('referred', referred); // igual actualizamos la expiración en localStorage
}
</script>
```

Y creo que con eso se cierra el ciclo. Si te fijas, estoy declarando una variable `correct_value` que es el valor de la cookie (sólo lo que viene antes del underscore). Si el localStorage pisa la cookie, también actualiza `correct_value`.

Levanté ese ejemplo en https://examples.ffflabs.com/setcookie.php

---

## Algunos flujos posibles

**Flujo Inicial** entras a https://examples.ffflabs.com/setcookie.php?ref=1234

Entras por primera vez. No hay valor en `$_COOKIES`. Detecta el ref 1234 y fija ese valor. El browser dice:

> **Acción en el backend:** 
>   se detectó en el parámetro ref la cookie con
>   valor 1234 y se fijó su expiración a 1540046455
>
> **Detección en el frontend** 
>   El browser detectó la cookie "referred" con valor 1234 y
>   expiración 1540046455
>
> **Detección en localStorage** 
>   localStorage no tiene una llave "deferred". 
>   Se asignó el valor de la cookie: 1234_1540046455

Si abres Chrome Devtools, pestaña Application sección Storage, podrás ver el valor de la cookie (**puede que tengas que apretar el botón de refresco** si no aparece la cookie)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el valor en localStorage:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Segundo Flujo**: entras a https://examples.ffflabs.com/setcookie.php?ref=4321 (estás cambiando el ref)

El backend ya tiene la cookie `1234`. Ignora el ref y el frontend dice:

> **Acción en el backend**: se detectó la cookie con valor 1234 y se extendió su expiración a 1540046974
>
> **Detección en el frontend**: El browser detectó la cookie "referred" con valor 1234 y expiración 1540046974
>
> **Detección en localStorage**: El valor almacenado en localStorage coincide con el valor de la cookie: 1234

Si examinas Chrome Devtools el valor de la cookie y localStorage no ha cambiado. Persististe la cookie aunque se especificó otro ref en la URL.

---

**Tercer Flujo:** borras la cookie pero mantienes el valor en localStorage. Navegas a https://examples.ffflabs.com/setcookie.php?ref=4321

El frontend dice:

> **Acción en el backend**: se detectó en el parámetro ref la cookie con valor 4321 y se fijó su expiración a 1540047450
>
> **Detección en el frontend**: El browser detectó la cookie "referred" con valor 4321 y expiración 1540047450
>
> **Detección en localStorage**: El valor en localStorage 1234 es distinto al de la cookie 4321. Se sobreescribió la cookie con ese valor

Recargas la página y verás que gracias a localStorage restableciste el referrer 1234.

---

**Cuarto Flujo:** Modificas el valor de localStorage a `2468_1540047515`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu cookie sigue diciendo `1234_1540047515`. Navegas a https://examples.ffflabs.com/setcookie.php?ref=4321

El frontend te responde:

> **Acción en el backend**: se detectó la cookie con valor 1234 y se extendió su expiración a 1540047771
>
> **Detección en el frontend**: El browser detectó la cookie "referred" con valor 1234 y expiración 1540047771
>
> **Detección en localStorage**: El valor en localStorage 2468 es distinto al de la cookie 1234. Se sobreescribió la cookie con ese valor

En el fondo, lo que hay en localstorage (si está vigente) manda sobre la cookie . Si recargas, ahora el referrer es `2468`

---

**Quinto Flujo:** fijas en localstorage un valor distinto y un **timestamp expirado** `1357_1500047942`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El frontend responde:

> **Acción en el backend**: se detectó la cookie con valor 2468 y se extendió su expiración a 1540047942
>
> **Detección en el frontend**: El browser detectó la cookie "referred" con valor 2468 y expiración 1540047942
>
> **Detección en localStorage**: El valor en localStorage expiró o no tiene valor. Se le asignó el valor de la cookie: 2468_1540047942

LocalStorage se ha sobreescrito con el valor de la cookie porque está expirado y hay que renovarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Último Flujo:** borras la cookie. Borras localStorage. Recargas la página https://examples.ffflabs.com/setcookie.php?ref=1234

Recibes la misma respuesta que en el flujo inicial (aunque los timestamps han cambiado). Si revisas Chrome DevTools verás que la cookie y localStorage almacenaron lo que acaba de pasarles el backend.

---

## Conclusiones al Cierre

Cuando termina el flujo completo, la variable `correct_value` siempre tiene el valor correcto de la cookie.

- El valor inicial si es la primera visita
- El valor original si el visitante borró la cookie o se reinició el servidor o se venció la sesión en el servidor
- El valor nuevo si han pasado 30 días desde la última visita

Por lo que, si tu intención original era asociar un usuario a un referrer en forma semipermanente, entonces al final del flujo puedes enviar mediante Ajax el dato `correct_value` a otro endpoint (e.g. `asociar_referrer.php`) que persista el usuario y su referrer por ejemplo en una base de datos.

Esta persistencia **debe permitir insertar si no hay valor para ese usuario, o actualizar si ya existe**. En MySQL eso se puede hacer usando algo como

```
INSERT INTO usuario_ref (id_usuario, referrer) VALUES (1, '1234')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE referrer='1234';
```

Si el id del usuario es una llave primaria, va a insertar el registro si no existe, y reemplazarlo si ya existe.

Esto mismo en PostgreSQL tiene una sintaxis parecida:

```
INSERT INTO usuario_ref (id_usuario, referrer) VALUES (1, '1234')
  ON CONFLICT (id_usuario) DO UPDATE SET referrer='1234';
```

Comment: Hola, Gracias por su gran respuesta e explicación :)

Comment: amigo existe un error de `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'` en la linea 11, cual corresponde a `setcookie('referred', implode('|',[$referred,$expiration], $expiration, '/');` todo parece estar bien, como lo soluciono amigo, para mí todo parece estar en orden.

Comment: Disculpa amigo y al código `javascript` debo copiarlo tal como está o debo agregar el código dentro de un `$(function () {  });` y como puedo saber si el código `javascript` está funcionando correctamente :)

Comment: Voy a reescribir la respuesta con el ejemplo completo